# Visual Studio iOS deployment fails because "The edge module has not been pre-compiled"

Tags: ios, node.js, visual-studio, cordova, edge.js

I am trying to deploy a HTML/CSS/JS Apache Cordova application from a windows machine to a Mac.  I believe they are communicating properly through the remotebuild agent but when I attempt to build a blank project to deploy on the Mac this error is thrown at the very beginning of the build:

```
MDAVSCLI : error : The edge module has not been pre-compiled for node.js version v4.1.1. You must build a custom version of edge.node. Please refer to https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge for building instructions.
```

I have followed the link and have searched for the solution as to how to fix this error but the link does not seem to apply to what I am doing at all.  I am not using any node.js functions in my code so I am confused as to why this error is occuring.  I am only trying to build a nearly blank HTML page and I still get the error regardless of how simple I make the page.

How can I go about fixing this solution? what is the best way to get rid of this error or to as the error suggests pre-compile edge to work with node.js version 4.1.1?

Comment: you have a misconception about how Cordova works. You say you want to deploy to a *Mac*, but I think you mean iOS.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed Dustin? I'm getting the same now and cant find a good solution to the problem.

Comment: Neil, I never found a way to fix it.  I had to create a phone gap project on my mac and then copy and paste the code I had been working on in visual studio into the phone gap  project in order to deploy my app over iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with Cordova 5.3.1 and Node v4.
https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/blob/master/articles/known-issues/known-issues-ios.md#building-for-ios-hangs-when-nodejs-v40-is-installed

I fixed by uninstalling Node v4.1.1 and installing Node v0.12.7
https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Answer (score 0):

@Dustin,
you have a misconception about how Cordova works. You say you want to deploy to a *Mac*, but I think you mean iOS. If so, you should read:

*What's needed for iOS Development?*
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/bf1Hgkel3W4

**I Quote**

> The short and sweet of it is as follows:
>
> - You need OS X + Xcode
> - You need several iDevices
> - You need $99/year for Apple Developer program (which you've already indicated is not a problem)
>
> All of the above = cost-of-doing-business.

If you read the entire thread (especially the part from Kerri Shotz), you will get more information and more options.

Best of Luck

Comment: No I know how it works very well I have all those components, have had experience using them, and have published an app in the app store.  I mean deploy to a mac so i can use the code on iOS devices.  The problem I am running into concerns visual studio and its remote client called "remotebuild".  I have used it before but something changed or a newer version came out that gave me this error.

Comment: Okay. Your comments lead me to believe I am not getting the entire story. Nonetheless, over the last few days two (2) things have happen. **1)** Apple upgrade devices in the field to iOS 9.0.1 **2)** if you did NOT assign a version to the compiler to use with the project, then you got the latest, and you have problems. You can read the details here - [Current Tripping Points to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/current-tripping-points.md) -- Best of Luck

Answer (score 0):

After losing a fair bit of hope and following a lot of posts, blogs and bug work-arounds with no luck I decided to click on the 'Run Dependency Checker' button in Visual Studio - Tools -> Options -> Tools For Apache Cordova -> Cordov Tools. This checker told me that Joyent Node.js wast installed. I did have node.js and npm set up on the latest version, im not sure what the difference is.

I went through the process of modifying the VS installation (change or remove a program) and sure enough Joyent Node.js wasnt checked. I cheked it and it went through the process of installing.

My VS installation now looks like the below and my project is building without:

```
MDAVSCLI : error : The edge module has not been pre-compiled for node.js version v4.1.1
```

[image]